The "=" button is not in the place it is supposed to be
The "=" button is supposed to be in the 9,6,3 column while whatever I do it just keeps getting pushed to the right side into the "+" button. This is the code:
import tkinter as tk
import math

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Simple Calculator")

# Define button height, width, and padding
BUTTON_HEIGHT = 2
BUTTON_WIDTH = 5
BUTTON_PADDING = (10, 0)  # Padding from top

# Create entry widget
entry = tk.Entry(root, width=20, font=("Arial", 14))
entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, pady=BUTTON_PADDING)  # Add some padding to top

def button_click(value):
    current = entry.get()
    entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry.insert(0, current + value)

def clear():
    entry.delete(0, tk.END)

def calculate():
    try:
        result = eval(entry.get())
        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        entry.insert(0, str(result))
    except Exception as e:
        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        entry.insert(0, "Error")

def square_root():
    try:
        value = float(entry.get())
        result = math.sqrt(value)
        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        entry.insert(0, str(result))
    except Exception as e:
        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        entry.insert(0, "Error")

# Create clear button to the left of the % button
tk.Button(root, text='C', width=BUTTON_WIDTH, height=BUTTON_HEIGHT, command=clear).grid(row=1, column=0)

# Create % button above the number buttons in the top-left corner
tk.Button(root, text='%', width=BUTTON_WIDTH, height=BUTTON_HEIGHT, command=lambda: button_click('%')).grid(row=1, column=1)

# Create square root button to the right of the % button
tk.Button(root, text='√', width=BUTTON_WIDTH, height=BUTTON_HEIGHT, command=square_root).grid(row=1, column=2)

# Create buttons for numbers
numbers = [
    '7', '8', '9',
    '4', '5', '6',
    '1', '2', '3',
    '.', '0', '='
]

row_num = 2
col_num = 0

for number in numbers:
    if number == '=':
        tk.Button(root, text=number, width=BUTTON_WIDTH, height=BUTTON_HEIGHT, command=calculate).grid(row=row_num, column=col_num, columnspan=2)
        col_num += 2  # Increment column number by 2
    else:
        tk.Button(root, text=number, width=BUTTON_WIDTH, height=BUTTON_HEIGHT, command=lambda value=number: button_click(value)).grid(row=row_num, column=col_num)
        col_num += 1
    if col_num > 2:  # Check if column number exceeds 2
        col_num = 0  # Reset column number
        row_num += 1  # Move to the next row

# Create buttons for operations
operations = [
    '/', '*', '-', '+', 
]

# Update the initial row and column numbers for operation buttons
row_num = 2
col_num = 3

for operation in operations:
    tk.Button(root, text=operation, width=BUTTON_WIDTH, height=BUTTON_HEIGHT, command=lambda value=operation: button_click(value)).grid(row=row_num, column=col_num)
    row_num += 1

# Run the main loop
root.mainloop()

I tried to fix it and the problem just kept getting worse. It would really help if somebody would help (I even tried to use ChatGPT but the problem couldn't be fixed).

Please create a minimal reproducible example and show as an actual example of the expected and the observed result.

You use the same button width as for other buttons but place it in a wider cell in which it is centered by default.

The problem is caused by the addition columnspan=2 inside the chained .grid method:
for number in numbers:
    if number == '=':
        tk.Button(root, text=number, width=BUTTON_WIDTH, height=BUTTON_HEIGHT, 
                  command=calculate)\
            .grid(row=row_num, column=col_num, columnspan=2)

Get rid of it, and all will be well. That said, you could perhaps benefit from an easier setup.  Loop through a single list of lists that contain your buttons and then get the proper command from a dict:
# delete all between `def square_root()` and `def square_root()` and insert:

# list of lists (desired grid)
buttons = [
    ['C', '%', '√'],
    ['7', '8', '9', '/'],
    ['4', '5', '6', '*'],
    ['1', '2', '3', '-'],
    ['.', '0', '=', '+']
]

# dict with custom commands
custom_commands = {
    'C': clear,
    '%': lambda: button_click('%'),
    '√': square_root,
    '=': calculate
    }

# skip n rows
row_skip = 1

# loop `buttons`, `command` from `dict` (`default` numbers), create `tk.Button`
for row, button_list in enumerate(buttons):
    for column, button in enumerate(button_list):
        command = custom_commands.get(button, 
                                      lambda value = button: button_click(value))
        (
            tk.Button(root, text = button, width = BUTTON_WIDTH, 
                  height = BUTTON_HEIGHT, command = command)
            .grid(row = row_skip + row, column = column)
         )



The "=" button is supposed to be in the 9,6,3 in column.

The problem can be fixed.
Just two minor changes.
You ready to go.
in line 61:
row_num = 2

to:
row_num = 1

In line 66, remove columnspan=2 in Button widget.


tk.Button(root, text='%', width=BUTTON_WIDTH, height=BUTTON_HEIGHT,
command=lambda: button_click('%')).grid(row=1, column=1)



Screenshot:

